# how to extract the year that the minimum or maximum value occures from csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have years in CSV file vertically at the left and a column of data need to find the minimum data and the year when the minimum value occurs

Comment: use `pandas` to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to analyze and performs queries to csv files is to load them in memory with a [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame), what this does is convert your csv content into an object in tabular form that be manipulated at will within Python using simple methods and arguments.

Depending on your development environment package installation will be slightly different, I recommend that you use virtual environments for all your projects take a look at [this medium post](https://enniomaldonado.medium.com/set-up-a-shell-python-development-environment-from-scratch-part-2-python-working-with-4361eab5df51) for more details on how to do that.

for Anaconda:

```
conda install pandas
```

for other python installations:

```
pip install pandas
```

Toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)

# Show first 5 rows of DataFrame
df.head()

#Find the row where the value on column of interest is min
df[df['column_name'].min()]
```

Kind regards

Comment: sorry I was asked not to use pandas but only import CSV

Comment: Then you will have to use the CSV library included in Python itself to read the file by doing:  csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams), check: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html for mroe details and examples on how to iterate on each row.